# Magento Convert timezone

Tags: magento-1.9, datetime, convert

I have an input array data containing time in 'Y-m-d h:i:s' format and the gmt timezone data  like this:

```
$time = array(
           "time" => "2017-11-01 12:00:12"
           "gmt"  => "+7"
        );
```

i wish to convert the above time data into a date with format from magento locale config timezone, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
   echo $value['name'].' joined on [ Date: '.date('d M Y',strtotime($value['date'])).' , Time:'.date('H:i',strtotime($value['date']));
}
```